# string Date Format, C# ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm completely new to C# Asp.Net, and having trouble formatting the following string:

```
string defTo = string.Format (@"{0:yyyy\/MM\/dd}" , DateTime.Now);
```

It prints as:   `YYYYMMDD`

I would like it to print as: `YYYY/MM/DD`     <- Notice the forward slashes.

Can someone point out how I could achieve this?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me as-is.  How are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string defTo =DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backslashes:

```
string defTo = string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
string defTo = string.Format("{0:dd\\/MM\\/yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
```

EDIT: This should work too:

```
"{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a escape character for "/" just remove it:

```
string defTo = string.Format ( @"{0:yyyy/MM/dd}" , DateTime.Now );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the forward slashes since you declared it a literal string `@"..."`.

Anything inside the quotes are "as-is" except for other quote characters. To escape them you should double them:

```
var str1 = @"this is a ""double quote"" in a literal string";
```